# aws --exclude is causing an issue, unable to exclude successfully

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am trying to mv all the .jpg images that are directly under /images to /images/category but it is not working for me, I am unable to figure out what I am doing wrong.

I tried the solution suggested at several SO questions but none seem to work for me.

Any help regarding this would be much appreciated.

Below is the output of ls command which shows the folder structure.
[image: Output of ls command]

The mv command I am using.

Edit: `aws s3 cp --dryrun s3://copypath/ s3://pastepath --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*.jpg" --exclude "*"`

[image: cp command]

Amazon version
[image: aws version]

Comment: You've included the --dryrun option which displays the operations that would be performed, without actually running them.

Comment: yes, that was intentional, I wanted to see the output but I am not seeing any.

Comment: The command worked perfectly well for me. Could you please show your results? (Feel free to Edit your question to include the details, as text rather than a graphic please.)

Comment: The mv command in the 2nd image gives no output at all, I waited for like 15-20 mins but it does no processing. I will update the question so you can use the exact command I am using.